# Forcing Typescript to use arrow function when compiling

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to force typescript to use arrow function when compiling it to javascript as I am facing with this binding inside my typescript class.

I have a code as below.

But the above function when compiled to javascript throws error `this.method1 is undefined`.

I am not sure why this is causing an issue. Seems like the binding of `method2` is the issue.

I have tried manually processing the javascript compiled file and added the binding of `method2` to class. Then it works

```
export class1 {
   private method1(){}

   public method2(){
       this.method1();
   }
}
```

I want `method1` to be accessible from `method2`. Since arrow function doesn't need binding I need typescript to always compile the code to an arrow function

Comment: FYI, what you've typed out is not a class. And if it was just a typo, can you show how you are consuming this class so that we can identify what the real problem is?

Comment: Your code works for me (but I have to add the `class` keyword: `export class class1 {...`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
export class class1 {
   private method1(){}

   public method2 = () => {
       this.method1();
   }
}
```

Comment: The problem is there are many methods like that already written and now i have to change all the function to arrow function

Comment: @NithinBharathwaj This is the way class methods work on JS, TS implements the spec when downcompiling, and if you target es2015 or above the classes will be emitted as is without any changes (except for type erasure). If you want `this` to be bound you need to use arrow functions or you can create a function to iterate through the object props and bind all functions.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Thank you so much for help. I was able to get through the issue by changing all functions to arrow syntax.